# populating selectList in C# issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, dropdownbox

So i have this code,

```
var CityName = (from ct in db.ZipCodes orderby ct.CityName
                       where (ct.StateName.Equals(StateName))
                       select ct.CityName).ToList().Distinct();
SelectList city = new SelectList(CityName);
ViewBag.City = city;
```

which works perfectly fine, Now i needed some more conditions which fetch the correct result from the database. the query for that is this

```
select CityName from ZipCodes where StateName='New York' and CityType='D' group by CityName,AreaCode
```

now anyone please tell me how should i use the group by in this code, i tried but it gives me syntax error.

Also i tried creating a Stored Procedure

```
var CityName= db.sp_get_CityName(StateName).ToList();
```

but it populates the sp_get_citynameresult in drop down.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do like this

```
var Result =   (from ct in db.ZipCodes
                where ct.StateName == "New York" && ct.CityType == "D"
                group ct by new { ct.CityName,ct.AreaCode }into g
                select new {CityName = g.Key.CityName,AreaCode = g.Key.AreaCode,g.ToList()};
```

Comment: `var CityName1 =   (from ct in db.ZipCodes                               where ct.StateName == StateName && ct.CityType == "D"
group ct by new { ct.CityName,ct.AreaCode }into g
select new {g.Key.CityName}).ToList();` did the trick

Answer (score 1):

you can use below mentioned code.

```
var CityName=ZipCodes.Where(p=>p.StateName="New York" && CityType="D").GroupBy(q => new { q.AreaCode,q.CityName});
```